# How do I print private class variables from an unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have an unordered map containing one class instance per key. Each instance contains one private variable called source and a getter function called getSource().

My goal is to traverse the map, using my getter function to print the variable from each class instance. In terms of output formatting, I would like to print one variable per line. What is the proper print statement to accomplish this?

***unordered_map declarations:***

```
unordered_map<int, NodeClass> myMap; // Map that holds the topology from the input file
unordered_map<int, NodeClass>::iterator mapIterator; // Iterator for traversing topology map
```

***unordered_map traversal loop:***

```
// Traverse map
for (mapIterator = myMap.begin(); mapIterator != myMap.end(); mapIterator++) {
        // Print "source" class variable at current key value
}
```

***getSource():***

```
// getSource(): Source getter
double NodeClass::getSource() {
    return this->source;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] and be as specific about your problem as possible?

Comment: I shall do that now. Thank you!

My apologies, this is my first post on this website.

Comment: @key199 If this is your first post, you should've, **at the very least**, taken the [tour], and read on [ask]. And those pages should've already given you these guidelines already. So, _It's my first time_ is not an excuse.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links to the tour and how to ask. I shall read them immediately.

Comment: Thank  you for following the site rules. I've added an answer that I believe may be of help. Cheers.

Comment: You are very kind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An `unordered_map` constitutes of elements that are key-value pair. The key and value are correspondingly referred to as `first` and `second`.

Given your case, the int would be the key, and your NodeClass would be the value corresponding to the key.

As such, your question could be distilled to "how do I access the values of all keys stored in an `unordered_map`"?.

Here's an example that I hope would help:

```
        using namespace std;
        unordered_map<int, string> myMap;

        unsigned int i = 1;
        myMap[i++] = "One";
        myMap[i++] = "Two";
        myMap[i++] = "Three";
        myMap[i++] = "Four";
        myMap[i++] = "Five";

        //you could use auto - makes life much easier
        //and use cbegin, cend as you're not modifying the stored elements but are merely printing it.
        for (auto cit = myMap.cbegin(); cit != myMap.cend(); ++cit)
        {
            //you would instead use second->getSource() here.
            cout<< cit->second.c_str() <<endl;
            //printing could be done with cout, and newline could be printed with an endl
        }
```